# FileNotFoundError - Trouble opening an image from WindowsPath object

Tags: python, random, nested-lists, file-not-found, pathlib

Iterating through this list and reading/opening the images gives no error,you can see that each item (index 0) in the tuple is a WindowsPath object of pathlib module. So, this works:
[image: Working]

Iterating through this list does not work and the image is unable to be found, and you can see that each item(index 0) in the list is a WindowsPath that points to the WindowsPath object of pathlib module. I'd love to get this list to be the same as the list in the above image:
[image: Not Working]

To me, **it looks like it's trying to open a non-existent file called "[WindowsPath('dir1/img1.png')]"  instead of the existing file called "dir1/img1.png"**. Which seems to stem from calling function random_list() and then appending the output of that function to a list.

See below code:

```
def random_list():
    #set empty list
    combo = []
    #mapping images to probabilities
    for d, p in zip(layers, probabilities):
        #random choice of image given the probability
        ch = choices(d, p)
        #add image path to list
        combo.append(ch)
    #return list in order to add more images, total of 7 loops
    return combo
           
'''
Main method
'''
#makes a list of all .png images in the given directories
layers = [list(Path(directory).glob("*.png")) for directory in ("dir1/", "dir2/", "dir3/", "dir4/", "dir5/", "dir6/", "dir7/")]

#list of probabilities for each image
probabilities =
                [ [0.17, 0.11, 0.15, 0.085, 0.05, 0.235, 0.2],
                 [0.075, 0.6, 0.3, 0.025],
                 [0.075, 0.3, 0.6, 0.025],
                 [0.3, 0.075, 0.6, 0.025],
                 [0.55, 0.35, 0.1],
                 [0.1, 0.55, 0.35],
                 [0.1, 0.35, 0.55] ]

#setting empty list
combinations = []
 
#while combinations is less than 1,111 items:
while len(combinations) < 1111:
    #get random list of traits
    a = random_list()
    #add to list if unique
    if a not in combinations:
        combinations.append(a)


#calling iterative function which layers images from directories and saves them
generate(layers)
```

ERROR:

```
 File "E:\myDir\subDir\imageGeneratorTest.py", line 22, in generate
        layer = Image.open(str(path), "r")
    
      File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\PIL\Image.py", line 2968, in open
        fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
    
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "[WindowsPath('dir1/img1.png')]"
```

Comment: Haven't worked through the code yet but `[WindowsPath('dir1/img1.png')]` is a list with a single path object.

Comment: @tdelaney Exactly, and I'd want it to just be the reference to the path. I believe it's because I call a function to add the paths to a list and then add that list to another list given that the combination of images is unique. I have tried taking out that function all together, but it only appends 1 image path into index 0 of "combinations" rather than a list of 7 paths to index 0. And it has no problem finding the image when that function random_list() is non existent. Just can't get it to work, been at it for hours. Last piece of the puzzle for me

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body.

Comment: @novonimo apologies, I must have overthought how much information to add. Deleted some of the text but left the code in there for reproduction purposes.

Comment: @novonimo also actually got rid of the code for generate() function, I know the code for that is fine and is not causing the issue

Comment: it's very better now. thank you for your edition and responsibility.

Comment: @novonimo no problem, I was thinking of mapping char or ints to each path and adding those to the list initially, and then passing those values into the list that ultimately gets iterated through. But, I can not think of any other solution that may work unless there is an easy way to convert or reference the single item list containing the WindowsPath obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this worked for me:

```
while len(genList) < 1111:
    a = random_list()

    #add to list if unique
    if a not in genList:
        genList.append(a)

combinations = list([str(c) for c in lst] for lst in genList)
```

and then taking the junk out of string in my iterative function with this line:

```
path = (path.replace("[WindowsPath('", "")).replace("')]", "")
```